# Pivot while changing data types (dynamically)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, pivot

Let's say I have 3 tables: users, customattributes, and customattributevalues.  End user can add custom attributes by selecting a name and type for the attribute, and the edit the values for any user.

Here are my users:

| id | firstname | lastname | active | datecreated | username | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Ellen | Ripley | 1 | 3/25/2235 | 78439 | Rip8439@Weyland-Yutani.com |
| 5 | Johnny | Rico | 1 | 4/16/2675 | Roughneck31 | RicoJ31@Roughnecks.com |

customattributes (can be added to anytime)

| id | fullname | uniquename | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hire Date | hiredate | date |
| 2 | Employee ID | eeid | int |
| 3 | Supervisor | supervisor | nvarchar(50) |
| 4 | Assigned Ship | assignedship | nvarchar(50) |
| 5 | Job Title | jobtitle | nvarchar(50) |

type I currently have as sysname datatype.

customattributevalues (can be edited anytime)

| id | attributeid | userid | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2335-03-25 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 78439 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | Burke, Carter |
| 4 | 4 | 3 | Sulaco |
| 5 | 5 | 3 | Consultant |
| 6 | 1 | 5 | 2675-04-16 |
| 7 | 2 | 5 | 78440 |
| 8 | 3 | 5 | LT Rasczak |
| 9 | 4 | 5 | Rodger Young |
| 10 | 5 | 5 | Private |

value I currently have as `sql_variant` datatype

So here is my question: how can I create a report that shows all employees and their attributes, 1 line per employee, without knowing how many custom attributes there are --and-- **crucially, I want to explicitly convert each column to the correct data type**

Desired output:

| firstname | lastname | datecreated | username | email | Hire Date | Employee ID | Supervisor | Assigned Ship | Job Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ellen | Ripley | 2235-03-25 | 78439 | Rip8439@Weyland-Yutani.com | 2335-03-25 | 78439 | Burke, Carter | Sulaco | Consultant |
| Johnnie | Rico | 2675-04-16 | Roughneck31 | RicoJ31@Roughnecks.com | 2675-04-16 | 78440 | LT Rasczak | Rodger Young | Private |

I've already learned to do the dynamic column headers using [dynamic queries](https://sqlskull.com/2020/06/16/sql-server-dynamic-pivot/#:%7E:text=Implementing%20Dynamic%20Pivot%20table%20%20%20SQL%20Basics,%20%20....More%20%205%20more%20rows%20), but it is the type conversion that is escaping me.

I'm adapting [this solution for custom fields](https://aboutsqlserver.com/2012/02/22/store-custom-fieldsattributes-in-microsoft-sql-server-database-part-2-namevalue-pairs/?unapproved=201416&moderation-hash=771c41a02ff9a7c909e93140a8795e3a#comment-201416), but the limitation to this solution is you have to know each custom field to make the type conversion.

Here is what I've tried.  I got the correct output, except for the type conversions.

Query:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @sqlcmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @columns += QUOTENAME(fullname) + ','
FROM customattributesx ca

ORDER BY ca.id;

SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

--PRINT @columns;

SET @sqlcmd = '
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT userid
        ,firstname
        ,lastname
        ,datecreated
        ,username
        ,email
        ,fullname
        ,value
    FROM (
        SELECT u.id as userid
              ,u.firstname
              ,u.lastname
              ,u.datecreated
              ,u.username
              ,u.email
              ,ca.id
              ,ca.fullname as fullname
              ,ca.uniquename
              ,ca.type
              ,cav.value as value
        FROM dbo.users u
        CROSS JOIN customattributesx ca
        INNER JOIN customattributevaluesx cav
            ON cav.attributeid = ca.id AND cav.userid = u.id

        --ORDER BY u.id asc, ca.id asc
    ) t1
) t2
PIVOT (
    MIN(value)
    FOR fullname IN ('+@columns+')
) as pivottable
';
--print @sqlcmd
EXECUTE (@sqlcmd)
```

Create Tables:

```
USE [CTMS]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[users]    Script Date: 11/24/2021 9:29:16 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [firstname] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [datecreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [username] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [emailconfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [passwordhash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [twofactorenabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [lockoutend] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [eockoutenabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [accessfailedcount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [qrcode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uk_email] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [email] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uk_qrcode] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [qrcode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uk_username] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [username] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[users] ADD  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [datecreated]
GO


USE [CTMS]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[customattributesx]    Script Date: 11/24/2021 9:31:09 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customattributesx](
    [id] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fullname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [uniquename] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [type] [sysname] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_customattributesx] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uk1_customattributesx] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [uniquename] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [CTMS]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[customattributevaluesx]    Script Date: 11/24/2021 9:31:27 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customattributevaluesx](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [attributeid] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [userid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [value] [sql_variant] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_customattributevaluesx] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uk1_customattributevaluesx] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [attributeid] ASC,
    [userid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[customattributevaluesx]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk1_customattributesvaluesx] FOREIGN KEY([attributeid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[customattributesx] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[customattributevaluesx] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk1_customattributesvaluesx]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[customattributevaluesx]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [fk2_customattributesvaluesx] FOREIGN KEY([userid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[customattributevaluesx] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk2_customattributesvaluesx]
GO
```

Comment: "convert each row to the correct data type" or each column? Of course you realise that a given column must have the same datatype in every row?

Comment: @DaleK I meant to type "convert each column to the correct data type."  the values are stored as sql_variants, but when pivoted each column has a consistent type, date, int, nvarchar, etc.

Comment: @DaleK I added another reference to the solution I've been working off of.

Comment: Since `pivot` has to have a single anchor column around which it pivots the results, you'd pivot based on the employee `id` then join the pivotted results on the employee table to lookup the `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: We want to see what you actually tried, not links to other solutions.

Comment: @DaleK okay added.  I had to adapt it to simplified version I presented, the actual tables are slightly more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must convert the datatype (could really be a presentation layer thing), then a dynamic conditional aggregation should do the trick.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL nvarchar(max) ='
Select U.*' +
(
Select concat(',',quotename(fullname),'=max(case when attributeid=',id,' then try_convert(',type,',value) end)')
 From customattributes
 For XML Path ('')
)+'
 From  users U
 Join  customattributesvalues V on U.ID=V.userid
 Group By U.ID
         ,U.FirstName
         ,U.LastName
         ,U.active
         ,U.datecreated
         ,U.username
         ,U.email
'
--print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

[image]

**The Generated SQL Looks Like This**

```
Select U.*
      ,[Hire Date]=max(case when attributeid=1 then try_convert(date,value) end)
      ,[Employee ID]=max(case when attributeid=2 then try_convert(int,value) end)
      ,[Supervisor]=max(case when attributeid=3 then try_convert(nvarchar(50),value) end)
      ,[Assigned Ship]=max(case when attributeid=4 then try_convert(nvarchar(50),value) end)
      ,[Job Title]=max(case when attributeid=5 then try_convert(nvarchar(50),value) end)
 From  #users U
 Join  #customattributesvalues V on U.ID=V.userid
 Group By U.ID
         ,U.FirstName
         ,U.LastName
         ,U.active
         ,U.datecreated
         ,U.username
         ,U.email
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Is there a way to modify this so bit types can be used?  I think I can get away with not allowing bit types, but would like to maximize flexibility if possible.

Comment: @TristenHannah Depends.  How hare the bits being stored in the values table?   1/0 or true/false

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with true/false opton- I thought they were always 1/0

Comment: @TristenHannah You are correct regarding the 1/0.  I wasn't clear on how you were storing them.   Are you saying try_convert(bit,value) doesn't work?

Comment: it's the MAX operator that doesn't work, and my understanding is all aggregate operators won't work.  However, no reason to despair, I think I can design around not allowing bit data types.

Comment: This solution seems to work with bit data types just modifying the dynamic select to: Select concat(',',quotename(fullname),'=try_convert(',type,',MAX(case when attributeid=',id,' THEN value END))')   (fourth line in the solution)

Comment: @TristenHannah Well done!

Answer (score 0):

`SQL_VARIANT` can be cast to a destination data type.

Modify part of the dynamic query where you generate column list, to generate two lists. One list is for `PIVOT` part and the other for `SELECT` part where you cast you data types.

Example is based on the [article you refer to in your question](https://sqlskull.com/2020/06/16/sql-server-dynamic-pivot/#:%7E:text=Implementing%20Dynamic%20Pivot%20table%20%20%20SQL%20Basics,%20%20....More%20%205%20more%20rows%20):

```
DECLARE @PivotList NVARCHAR( MAX )
DECLARE @SelectList NVARCHAR( MAX )
SELECT @SelectList = NULL, @PivotList = NULL
        -- Column list with CAST e.g. CAST( eeid AS INT ) AS eeid
        -- Data types come from your customattributes table
SELECT @SelectList = COALESCE( @SelectList + ',','') + 'CAST( ' + uniquename + ' AS [type] ) AS ' + uniquename,
        -- Just a column list that goes into PIVOT operator
        @PivotList = COALESCE( @PivotList + ',','') + uniquename
-- Your tables for attribute values and attribute type definitions
FROM customattributes AS ca

DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLQuery =

'SELECT StudID , '+@SelectList+'
FROM
( SELECT SM.StudID, S.SubjectName, SM.Score 
FROM StudentMarks SM 
INNER JOIN Subjects S
ON Sm.SubjectID = S.SubjectID
) AS tbl
PIVOT 
( Sum(Score)
FOR SubjectName IN ('+@PivotList+') ) as pvt'

EXEC(@SQLQuery)
```

Comment: Hi, I follow the SelectList and PivotList, but the SQL Query itself seems to be referencing other tables not included.  Still, I see where this is going and I think I can use the concept as a possible solution!